# PayPal Orders purchase_units: reference_id vs custom_id?

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk

I am working to set up orders and am a bit confused by the documentation, specifically these two seperate id's given to the `purchase_units`.

The documentation lists:

```
reference_id string
The API caller-provided external ID for the purchase unit. Required for multiple purchase units when you must update the order through PATCH. If you omit this value and the order contains only one purchase unit, PayPal sets this value to default.
```

and

```
custom_id string
The API caller-provided external ID. Used to reconcile client transactions with PayPal transactions. Appears in transaction and settlement reports but is not visible to the payer.
```

Both of them having the same `The API caller-provided external ID` bit confuses the two for me. It seems like one of these is meant to be the id I want to pass through to keep track of the order on the other side, and `custom_id` sounds more like that, but what is the `reference_id` supposed to be? It sounds like mostly the same thing, just the id I'd like to give it so I can keep track of it later.

If all of my orders will only have a single `purchase_item` is there any reason to use the `reference_id`?

Comment: did you find out how to pass custom order id to Paypal?

Comment: the `custom_id` field that I described above does that. Just make up your own ID's and put them there, then when you get a transaction notification of some kind, it will have whatever ID you gave it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `reference_id` is to distinguish between multiple `purchase_units` in a single order. Since all yours will have a single one, there is no reason to use it.

Use `custom_id` for any reconciliation needs, as it will be stored as part of the PayPal transaction.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250951/discussion-on-answer-by-preston-phx-paypal-orders-purchase-units-reference-id-v).

Comment: That is too bad, lots of useful information was shared here.

Comment: In order for all the shared info not to be lost, here is the summary of it all. The custom_id is an ID for a purchase unit. The custom_id can be anything, even a json string. The reference_id is a name for a purchase unit. The reference_id isn't stored anywhere, although it's still used to tell purchase_units apart when being operated on. It remains unclear how this is possible, when PayPal doesn't store it.

Comment: The PayPal-NET-SDK is for V1 and should not be used. The Checkout-NET-SDK is for V2 and can still be used. It still returns deprecated prop 'Payer', instead of 'PaymentSource'. It's unclear why.

Comment: When choosing an example source snippet from PayPal's dev site, go with the 'server' example (https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server). The client example does everything client side. It's for HTML client pages that don't call a server. If you want to do something automated on the server side, then you have to use the 'server' example. This can be made to work with the example create/capture order source, given on PayPal's Checkout-NET-SDK GitHub repo. This example source returns a HttpResponse, when it should be returning an Order. So editing is required to get it to work.

Comment: I'm currently continuing my research at PayPal's merchant tech support community, in the SDK section (https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/SDKs/Best-Way-To-Integrate-PayPal-In-A-C-Website/m-p/3026100).

Comment: "The custom_id is an ID for a purchase unit" .. no, `custom_id` is an optional field for your own id/metadata, and you can have one per purchase_unit. It can contain any data that will fit, and will be stored and visible as part of the resulting PayPal transaction in the receiver account. It is not visible to payers.

Comment: `reference_id` on the other hand, is a unique name for telling purchase_units apart when an order includes more than one and a particular one needs to be patched. It has no other use or purpose.